# react native undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I am wondering why am I getting an error like this undefined is not an object. Im trying to add a second screen on button press in the login.js

But I cant start the app cause of the undefined is not an object pointing here  const { navigate } = props.navigation;

Thank you guys

Here is my code

```
const login = (props) => {

    const { navigate } = props.navigation;


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

<View style={styles.img}>
      <Image source={require('./download.png')} />
      </View>
<View style={styles.but}>
     <Button
  onPress={() => navigate ('QR')}
  title="Sign in"
  color="#2f4f4f"
/>
</View>

      </View>

    );
}


login.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Login',
};


export default login
```

Here is my index.android.js

```
export default class Task extends Component {
  render() {

    const { navigation} = this.props;
    return (
      <Login navigation={navigation }/>
    )
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Login},
  SecondScreen: {screen: QR}
});
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the const { navigate }... line and also remove the onPress event handler?

Comment: const { navigate } = props.navigation; 
this statement is trying to access navigate property of navigation object and navigation is coming undefined , please check your props by logging it and see, if it even has navigation property(i dont think it has)

Comment: @JanPeter If i remove it the button wont work. I tried it

Comment: @ArnavYagnik I dont understand sir

Comment: just before const { navigate } = props.navigation; 
try console.log(props) 
and check if it has a navigation object and if it has , does it have a navigate property which is a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is cause by the wrong usage of navigator in  'index.android.js'.

Try to change the 'index.android.js' as below:

```
export default class Task extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SimpleApp />
    )
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Login},
  SecondScreen: {screen: QR}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(yourAppName, () => Task);
```

Hope it helps.